# Java - How to show Soap Fault

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws, soapfault

I have this kind of response when having a Soap Fault calling a Java Web Service

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:WaybillRegistrationFault xmlns:ns1="http://pod.waybillmanagement.ws.industrysystem.com.ar/">
                    <errors xmlns:ns2="http://pod.waybillmanagement.ws.industrysystem.com.ar/">
                        <code>80000</code>
                        <description>El número de CTG 20140904 ya existe</description>
                    </errors>
                    <errors xmlns:ns2="http://pod.waybillmanagement.ws.industrysystem.com.ar/">
                        <code>1000</code>
                        <description>La carta de porte ya se encuentra registrada.</description>
                    </errors>
                </ns1:WaybillRegistrationFault>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I did an Soap Handler with its handleFault method like this:
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {

```
    try {
        System.err.println("Handler handleFault");

        if (context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().hasFault()) {
            SOAPFault fa = context.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault();
            System.err.println(fa.getFaultString());
            System.err.println("FaultCode: " + fa.getFaultCode() + " - Detail: " + fa.getDetail());
        }
        return true;
    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        System.err.println("SoapEx " + ex.getMessage());
        return true;
    }
}
```

But in my output all I have is :

```
Handler handleFault
Fault occurred while processing.
FaultCode: soap:Server - Detail: [detail: null]
```

How do I process the errors node?

**Update:**

with `fa.getDetail().getFirstChild().getTextContent()` I get the text within the xml. How do I get that as an object. It be a WaybillRegistrationFault I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to print fault content as a xml string , you must convert the dom instance returned by the fa.getDetail() to String , fa.getDetail().toString() return ["+getNodeName()+": "+getNodeValue()+"]" not the content of the xml.

try the following;

```
String detailStr=dom2string(fa.getDetail())
System.err.println("FaultCode: " + fa.getFaultCode() + " - Detail: " + detailStr); 


public static final String dom2string(Node node) {
    try {
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Transformer tf = transformerThreadLocal.get();
        // Create writer
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(buffer, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);

        // transform
        tf.transform(new DOMSource(node), result);

        return sw.getBuffer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not convert Node to string", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Executing `fa.getDetail().getFirstChild().getTextContent()` I get the message but all in text format, is there a way to have it as an object?

Comment: fa.getDetail().getFirstChild() is the object you want

Comment: It's worth noticing that it's not an Java object, but an XML sort of object, which I had to parse through Node and NodeList.

Comment: I highly recommend using xmlbeans if you prefer handling xml document as objects instead of dom. Check http://xmlbeans.apache.org/

Answer (score 5):

This is the way that I always handle soap fault errors:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
new DOMSource(soapFaultException.getFault()), new StreamResult(sw));
String xml = sw.toString();
```